# Is there any way that service worker can delete the cache on device on every website update?

Tags: javascript, laravel, deployment, service-worker, web-development-server

Whenever I make any updates to my website, which is developed using Laravel, I have to delete the browser cache in order to reflect the changes. This is for both while working on localhost and when I deploy it on the server. Is there any way to automate the process, either by service worker where the cache is deleted after every new update?

Here is my serviceworker.js

```
 var staticCacheName = "pwa-v" + new Date().getTime();
var filesToCache = [
    '/offline.html',
    '/css/style.css',
    '/js/app.js',
];

// Cache on install
self.addEventListener("install", event => {
    this.skipWaiting();
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName)
            .then(cache => {
                return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
            })
    )
});

// Clear cache on activate
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
            return Promise.all(
                cacheNames
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName.startsWith("pwa-")))
                    .filter(cacheName => (cacheName !== staticCacheName))
                    .map(cacheName => caches.delete(cacheName))
            );
        })
    );
});

// Serve from Cache
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
            .then(response => {
                return response || fetch(event.request);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                return caches.match('/offline.html');
            })
    )
});
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting

Comment: @newUserName02 Thanks a lot for the link. I saw in the doc about cache bursting in production. I am using ElasticBeanstalk and upload my app through ElasticBeanstalk GUI.
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
is this code relevant to it?

Comment: Yes, that's what you will need in your webpack mix file. Also, you'll need to update the blade template that calls the compiled assets to use `{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}` and similar for css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet I am using to delete stale assets without manual intervention.

```
function deleteStaleAssets(url, asset) {
  caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then(function(cache) {
    cache.keys().then(function(keys) {
      let cc = keys.filter(function(req) {
        if(req.url.includes(asset) && req.url !== url) {
          return true;
        }
      });
      cc.forEach(function(r) {
        cache.delete(r);
      });
    });
  });
}

function onFetch(event) {
  var assets = ['/assets/application', 'assets/spree/frontend/all'];
  var asset = assets.find(function(asset) {
    return event.request.url.includes(asset);
  });
  if(asset) {
    event.respondWith(async function() {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
      const networkResponsePromise = fetch(event.request);

      event.waitUntil(async function() {
        const networkResponse = await networkResponsePromise;
        deleteStaleAssets(event.request.url, asset);
        await cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
      }());

      // Returned the cached response if we have one, otherwise return the network response.
      return cachedResponse || networkResponsePromise;
    }());
  }
  else {
    event.respondWith(
      // try to return untouched request from network first
      fetch(event.request).catch(function() {
        // if it fails, try to return request from the cache
        return caches.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
          if (response) {
            return response;
          }
          // if not found in cache, return default offline content for navigate requests
          if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' ||
            (event.request.method === 'GET' && event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html'))) {
            return caches.match('/offline.html');
          }
        })
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help!